# netcat/socat no response from other networking services

Tags: networking

First, I thought that this was [Vmware problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/141838/vmware-problems-networking-no-packet-response).

But now, after testing on several physical machines, I realized certain services didn't return response data when using socat/netcat 1.1 which is supposed to the latest version since last updated.

```
root@test3:~# netcat 192.168.1.2 25
220 762462a8c4d Microsoft ESMTP MAIL
Service, Version: 6.0.2600.5949 ready
at  Fri, 12 May 2010 18:04:20 +0600


EHLO localhost

sdfsafsd

^

root@test3:~#
```

I've tested it on both windows and linuxes. 
I found no problem with telnet.

Comment: Hi, cpbills, sorry for the output. Those are in wrong format when pasting. Just banner.


>220 762462a8c4d Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.2600.5949 ready at  T
ue, 18 May 2010 08:08:13 

So there any ways to type LF in nc in Windows command prompt?

Comment: Update:

There is no way to type LF in nc in Windows command prompt.

Comment: If your question is answered, you should accept answer instead of adding it to topic.

Answer (score 1):

Windows and it's services like to have a line-feed (LR) accompanying any carriage-returns (CR). Your shell won't generate the LF automatically. As a result of this, in your example, no commands would have been submitted to the receiving server.

You can insert an LR manually alongside your CR by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of each line. It will be displayed as `^M` and then a newline. Then you should receive the relevant responses from the server.

If you're using OpenSSL's `s_client` for talking to SSL services then you can use the argument `-crlf` to do it automagically for you.

Comment: Thanks, Dan Carley. 

I was forgetting this point.  I was insisting on thinking I get used to get outputs just by pressing "Enter". Ctrl+v,ENTER,Enter works at Linux but what about Windows?
Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you don't need to run the command like `netcat 192.168.1.2 25` and then type `EHLO` ?

from your question, it looks like you're typing your command as `netcat 192.168.1.2 25 220 762462a8c4d Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.2600.5949 ready at Fri, 12 May 2010 18:04:20 +0800 EHLO SAYHELLO VRFY TEST@LOCALHOST` and not `netcat 192.168.1.2 25`